# .profile function duplicates my argument in a string concat?

Tags: bash, function, shell, alias, string-concatenation

I use Git commit issue numbers in alignment with GitHub issues. To save time I wrote a bash function to creating a commit message like this:

```
git commit -m "#4 my commit message"
```

when calling

```
gci 4 "my commit message"
```

where 4 is the issue number, and the commit message follows.

However, my current implementation:

```
alias gcm='git commit -m '
gci(){
    index="${@:1}"
    message="#$index ${@:2}"
    gcm "$message"
}
```

yields the commit message twice:

```
$ gci 4 "my commit message"
[iss2 79d9540] #4 my commit message my commit message
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 h.z
```

What is causing the message to repeat twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${@:1}` and `${@:2}` does not work as you expect, use `$1` for first parameter and `$2` for the second:

```
alias gcm='git commit -m '
gci(){
    index="$1"
    message="#$index $2"
    gcm "$message"
}
```

As a side note, alias will not work in noninteractive shells.
No as to `${@:1}`, from [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

> ${var:pos}
>   Variable var expanded, starting from offset pos.

So if `"$@" == "4 my commit message"`, then:
`"${@:1}" == " my commit message"`
`"${@:2}" == "my commit message"`
As you are concatenating `${@:1} ${@:2}` you are seeing my commit message twice.

Comment: thanks so much. If I want this to work in noninteractive shells, should I just make two functions?

Comment: @highdimensional: yes. Even in interactive shells, use two functions :-)